# Query returns no data, even though I can access the DataBase in ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string, sql-server-express

I published an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application under the .NET Framework 4.5. 
The Server is a Windows 2012 R2 dedicated Server. The framework of the database is MS SQL Server 2016.

I changed the connectionString to:

```
<connectionStrings >
    <add name="ApplicationDbContext"
        connectionString="Server=server.de;Database=DataBase;User ID=UserName;Password=xxxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

When I built the project afterwards the server explorer refreshed and I could see the data base. Also I have full access to the database from the server explorer now. 
**But somehow every query in my project returns no data.** 
So, I tried to access the DB from a Controller method:

```
using (SqlConnection s = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server.de;Initial Catalog=DataBase;Integrated Security=False;User ID=UserName;Password= xxxxxxxx "))
{
    s.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = s.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM AspNetUsers;";
    string allUsers = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

To access the DB like this works perfectly.

Why can´t I access the DB by my standard DB-Context? It only works with the SqlConnection within the Code.
Is the ConnectionString right? Did I forget something else?

(I already updated SSTP to 2016 in VS)

This is my DB-Context:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {

        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        return userIdentity;
    }

    public int? BauunternehmenId { get; set; }

    public virtual Bauunternehmen Bauunternehmen { get; set; }

    public int? BauherrId { get; set; }

    public virtual Bauherr Bauherr { get; set; }


}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Bauunternehmen> MyBauunternehmen { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Bauherr> MyBauherr { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Baustelle> MyBaustelle { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Kamera> MyKamera { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Kameraprojekt> MyKameraprojekt { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Bild> MyBild { get; set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you put your EF code ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the db-context. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Hope you got the answer no ? If so please accept it with Up votes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is DefaultConnection? You don't show this connection string.... base should point to `ApplicationDbContext` such as `base("ApplicationDbContext")`

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("ApplicationDbContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```